# How to write a legend using dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize the following data: `dictMy = {'apple' : [[0, 1], [0, 2], [3, 2]], 'pear' : [[2, 3], [3, 5], [0, 2]], 'peach' : [[2, 5], [3, 8], [0, 0]]}` Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


dictMy = {'apple' : [[0, 1], [0, 2], [3, 2]], 'pear' : [[2, 3], [3, 5], [0, 2]], 'peach' : [[2, 5], [3, 8], [0, 0]]}

color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(dictMy))))

for key in dictMy:
    curLabel = key
    c=next(color)
    for item in dictMy[key]:
        x = item[0]
        y = item[1]
        plt.scatter(x,y, c = c)
    plt.legend(str(curLabel))
plt.show()
```

Here is the output I have:

[image: results from code]

So, I don't really get it, why does it show the legend in such a way and how this can be fixed. I more or less understand why it's the last of all keys, but I can't understand why is it split into letters. Please, help.

Comment: Apparently the `legend` function expects an iterable of strings, and you provide a string. When you iterate over a string, you get individual characters. You probably should not call `legend()` inside the loop.

Comment: @LevLevitsky thank you for the explanation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment you are calling the `legend` function for each `key` in your dictionary. You don't need to do this - simply label each of the types of points on your scatter plot with the dictionary key, and then call the `legend` function afterwards. The following will work:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


dictMy = {'apple' : [[0, 1], [0, 2], [3, 2]],
          'pear' : [[2, 3], [3, 5], [0, 2]],
          'peach' : [[2, 5], [3, 8], [0, 0]],
         }
color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(dictMy))))

for key, c in zip(dictMy, color):
    for idx, item in enumerate(dictMy[key]):
        x = item[0]
        y = item[1]
        if idx == 0:
            plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, label=key)
        else:
            plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]